# Using Dagger2 with PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, dagger-2, preferencefragment

I am working on Dependency Injection in my app using `Dagger2`. I have a Settings screen built using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. But since `Dagger2` does not provide a corresponding type for `PreferenceFragmentCompat` (like it provides `DaggerActivity` to replace `Activity` and `DaggerFragment` to replace `Fragment`), how can I use `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` when injecting the dependencies inside my Settings fragment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AndroidInjection.inject(fragment)` requires `fragment` to implement `dagger.android.HasAndroidInjector` as can be read from the `dagger.android.AndroidInjection` [source code](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjection.java).

`HasAndroidInjector` can be implemented just like how `DaggerFragment` is implemented ([source](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DaggerFragment.java)).

```java
public class SettingsFragment
  extends PreferenceFragmentCompat
  implements HasAndroidInjector {

  @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Object> androidInjector;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
    super.onAttach(context);
  }

  @Override
  public AndroidInjector<Object> androidInjector() {
    return androidInjector;
  }

  /* Other code */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked (with slight change though) :) Previously, I was using 'HasSupportFragmentInjector' in my Fragment and it did not work maybe because 'PreferenceFragmentCompat' does not support it. So, to use your solution, I updated all my Dagger2 Gradle dependencies from 2.16 to 2.24 and implemented HasAndroidInjector in my App class (not in Fragment class). And voila!